# Why PHP included element won't show in included sidebar?

Tags: php, include

I have site where I have global sidebar included on all pages with PHP. I'm trying to include contact information in that included sidebar and also include same contact information in main content of some pages.
Page construction is as followed:
Main content (in public_html) including contact information: include('contact.php');
contact.php is located in public_html
Included sidebar (from public_html/parts include('parts/sidebar.php')) including same contact information: include('../contact.php');
My problem is that contact information shows up only in main content and not in sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use dirname function of php

for example

file of sidebar

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/contact.php';
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you :)